# React Native [Android] "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1"

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

React Native 0.40.0 (not upgrading due to dependancies)

Running my application works fine in iOS, but fails on Android. Running

... app is running.. I get these:

```
03-12 16:53:23.866  4064  4067 I art     : Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=115KB
03-12 16:53:23.868  4064  4067 I art     : Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache
03-12 16:53:23.868  4064  4067 I art     : After code cache collection, code=110KB, data=87KB
03-12 16:53:35.584  4064  4067 I art     : Do partial code cache collection, code=117KB, data=103KB
03-12 16:53:35.591  4064  4067 I art     : After code cache collection, code=110KB, data=98KB
03-12 16:53:35.591  4064  4067 I art     : Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

... app is working fine here, for about 30 seconds. Then:

```
03-12 16:54:25.478  4064  4091 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x3c in tid 4091 (mqt_js)
03-12 16:54:25.479  1282  1282 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=4064 uid=10071 gid=10071 tid=4091
03-12 16:54:25.539  4150  4150 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-12 16:54:25.539  4150  4150 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:7.1.1/NYC/3756122:userdebug/test-keys'
03-12 16:54:25.539  4150  4150 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
03-12 16:54:25.539  4150  4150 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86'
03-12 16:54:25.539  4150  4150 F DEBUG   : pid: 4064, tid: 4091, name: mqt_js  >>> com.bideasy_rn <<<
03-12 16:54:25.539  4150  4150 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x3c
03-12 16:54:25.539  4150  4150 F DEBUG   :     eax 00000000  ebx 8e2f9d9c  ecx fffffffb  edx 8bc21340
03-12 16:54:25.539  4150  4150 F DEBUG   :     esi 00000000  edi 00000000
03-12 16:54:25.539  4150  4150 F DEBUG   :     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
03-12 16:54:25.539  4150  4150 F DEBUG   :     eip 8def474b  ebp 00000000  esp 8cc9aef0  flags 00010286
03-12 16:54:25.540  4150  4150 F DEBUG   :
03-12 16:54:25.540  4150  4150 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
03-12 16:54:25.540  4150  4150 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0006174b  /data/app/com.bideasy_rn-1/lib/x86/libjsc.so
03-12 16:54:25.540  4150  4150 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 001031c3  /data/app/com.bideasy_rn-1/lib/x86/libjsc.so
03-12 16:54:25.540  4150  4150 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00128294  /data/app/com.bideasy_rn-1/lib/x86/libjsc.so
03-12 16:54:25.540  4150  4150 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00142c10  /data/app/com.bideasy_rn-1/lib/x86/libjsc.so
03-12 16:54:25.540  4150  4150 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00003aa3  <anonymous:8ce0d000>
03-12 16:54:25.865  1608  4155 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.bideasy_rn/.MainActivity
03-12 16:54:25.865  1282  1282 W         : debuggerd: resuming target 4064
03-12 16:54:25.866  1608  1626 I BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-12 16:54:25.874  1324  1324 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/4064/oom_score_adj; errno=22
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W ActivityManager: Failed setting process group of 4064 to 1
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given thread 4090 does not exist
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W System.err:    at android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Native Method)
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.applyOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:20514)
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:21013)
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processCurBroadcastLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:272)
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:1222)
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue$BroadcastHandler.handleMessage(BroadcastQueue.java:172)
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W System.err:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-12 16:54:25.875  1608  1622 W System.err:    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
03-12 16:54:25.916  1326  2691 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-12 16:54:25.918  1608  3253 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-12 16:54:25.918  1608  3253 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
03-12 16:54:25.918  1608  3253 W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
03-12 16:54:25.918  1608  3253 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
03-12 16:54:25.919  1326  2691 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-12 16:54:25.921  1326  2691 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-12 16:54:25.931  1608  1649 W InputDispatcher: channel '81601ec com.bideasy_rn/com.bideasy_rn.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-12 16:54:25.931  1608  1911 I ActivityManager: Process com.bideasy_rn (pid 4064) has died
03-12 16:54:25.931  1608  1649 E InputDispatcher: channel '81601ec com.bideasy_rn/com.bideasy_rn.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-12 16:54:25.932  1608  1911 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 4064
03-12 16:54:25.935  1335  1335 I Zygote  : Process 4064 exited due to signal (11)
03-12 16:54:25.935  1608  2048 D GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 6
03-12 16:54:25.939  1608  2978 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{81601ec u0 com.bideasy_rn/com.bideasy_rn.MainActivity}
03-12 16:54:25.939  1608  2978 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '81601ec com.bideasy_rn/com.bideasy_rn.MainActivity (server)'
03-12 16:54:25.955  1326  1374 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-12 16:54:25.966  1326  1374 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-12 16:54:25.977  1326  1374 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-12 16:54:25.991  1326  1371 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-12 16:54:26.003  1326  1371 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-12 16:54:26.010  1326  1371 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
03-12 16:54:26.055  2174  2174 I OptInState: There is a new client and it does not support opt-in. Dropping request.
03-12 16:54:26.061  2174  2174 I MicroDetectionWorker: Micro detection mode: [mDetectionMode: [1]].
03-12 16:54:26.062  2174  2174 I AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
03-12 16:54:26.069  2174  4159 I MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
03-12 16:54:26.070  2174  3856 I MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@5bfbfc2
03-12 16:54:26.071  1337  1361 W APM_AudioPolicyManager: getInputForAttr() failed opening input: samplingRate 16000, format 1, channelMask 10
03-12 16:54:26.072  2174  3856 E AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 1049, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
03-12 16:54:26.072  2174  3856 E AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
03-12 16:54:26.072  2174  3856 E android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
03-12 16:54:26.073  2174  3856 I MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@5bfbfc2
03-12 16:54:26.074  2174  3856 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
03-12 16:54:26.076  2174  4159 W SpeechLevelGenerator: Really low audio levels detected. The audio input may have issues.
03-12 16:54:26.079  2174  2174 I MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
03-12 16:54:26.080  2174  3856 I MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@5bfbfc2
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 I MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  2429 I MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor: Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor:    ... 4 more
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 I AudioController: internalShutdown
It looks like the microphone, which I don't even use, is crashing the application.
```

How can I troubleshoot this further? The application seems to work fine for a few seconds, then something causes it to crash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicated right here :

`onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
03-12 16:54:26.082  2174  4159 W ErrorProcessor: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream`

Comment: I see that in the stack-trace. Any elaboration on what that is and how to fix it? I don't do anything with shared speech.

Comment: could you make a breakpoint in you code and try debugging or if you can post your piece of code that you think is causing the problem

Comment: I have no idea where in the code is causing the issue. The fact that I can do nothing to the app for (roughly, and inconsistently) 30 seconds, or interact with it, and then it crashes, makes it hard to imagine where it is.

Hard to set a breakpoint in this situation I think -- I'll look at the official docs

Comment: did you try to leave your app in debbuging mode to see what it say when it crashed ? i mean open the app in the debugging mode , and see what it say.

Comment: @NathanHyland have you found an answer for this?